# Why does permanent magnet not exhibit macroscopic quantum effect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, many-body, decoherence, open-quantum-systems

Permanent magnets are a result of quantum mechanics, i.e. quantum spin of electrons inside the magnet aligning.
Quantum spin follows the uncertainty principle. If I measure the spin orientation first in the X axis, then the Y axis, the second measurement would have 50/50 chance of being Y+/Y- (the [Stern–Gerlach experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment)).

Why does this not happen macroscopically? Since spins are aligned in a permanent magnet, why doesn't measuring the magnetic poles of a magnet demagnetize it, since that would "reset" the spin alignment in the orthogonal direction?

My understanding of quantum mechanics is at a pop-science level.

Comment: It is actually a complicated issue, because you have to deal with a (macroscopic) system which e.g. is thermally coupled to the surroundings. Ignoring this for a moment, you describe a system which is in an eigenstate of the magnetization (again, neglecting things and assuming the time evolution does not change this). And this is the observable you are concerned of--and as you might know, if the system is in an eigenstate of some observable, repeated measurements give the same value.

Answer (score 0):

The ferromagnetic state is a temperature equilibrium state, that has its minimum energy for temperature $T=0$ all spins aligned. Spins are fixed orbital currents for total angular momentum $\hbar/2$ of a single outer electron orbital. As such they can combine to orbit small volumes of lattice points parallel oriented to make up a microscopic, but quantized magnetic dipole.

These magnetic units can be oriented chaotically in their common total magnetic field. The chaotic noise by thermally induced reorientating and changing the boundaries between the regions of alignment is called spin noise.

The spontaneous change of orientation becomes more and more improbable with the Boltzmann factor $e^{-\frac{\Delta E}{k T}},$ simply by the growing energy $\Delta E$ to borrow from the system for a  flip with growing volume of the microscopic spins.

During the magnetizing process of a not magnetic probe in an external field one can hear the noise using a magnetic microphone (Barkhausen effect).